# Linux - QNAP - Can't change owner of folder

Tags: linux, chown, qnap

I have logged into the QNAP using ssh.

I am trying to change the owner of the a folder.

Here is what I am doing.

```
[/share/Users] # chown joe.dove JoeDove
```

And this is the response I get.

```
chown: unknown group name: dove
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: Make sure "dove" group exists. You may use "getent group dove"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qnap uses the busybox implementation of chown which treats the dot as the separator between user and group so it thinks the user is joe and the group is doe.

What can you do is use the UID with chown in this case. A oneliner to accomplish that would be:

```
chown $(awk -F ":" '/joe.doe/ {print $3}' /etc/passwd) JoeDove
```